# Currently no logon servers available to service the logon request (VPN and file share)

Tags: active-directory, vpn, authentication, network-share

I have a remote user with a laptop joined to our domain.

He can successfully log onto the machine.

While he is out of the office, he connects using SSL VPN, which connects and passes traffic.

When he attempts to hit the fileshare on the network, he gets the message:

> "\[address] is not accessible. You might not have permission to use
>   this network resource. contact the administrator of the server to find
>   out if you have access permissions. There are currently no logon
>   servers available to service the logon request."

I am assuming that his request is not being properly authenticated via active directory.  Should I have him try to NET USE with his domain credentials to see if it lets him in?

Oddly, he tells me that sometimes it does work over the VPN, but I cannot fathom why it would authenticate sometimes and not others.

Comment: Can he ping the AD servers? Can he resolve internal DNS requests?

Comment: What DNS server(s) are being assigned to the VPN client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server in questions was not correctly licensed.   After fixing the licensing issue, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, your user has one of two problems:

1) The VPN is not configured to forward *all* traffic through the VPN. If this is the case, then it's possible that you've only configured the VPN to allow certain traffic to traverse the VPN. Something (DNS, LDAP, etc) might be getting lost along the way.

2) Your client isn't configured to use your internal AD DNS servers when he is connected remotely.

When these problems are exhibited, you should run Wireshark or Netmon on both ends to see where the problem is. It should be fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS is up and he get that error, its a DNS problem. If he can't ping the AD servers once logged into the VPN, its not going to work. So you need to check your VPN/Firewall settings. In a VPN connection you should have access to all resources just as if you were sitting in the office LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. The user's password had expired while he was disconnected. His laptop still let him in because it cached the old password, but accessing network resources via VPN always resulted in the error.